# How to make a dir in Ruby

Tags: ruby

So I'm making this project in Ruby, and I copied this code from somewhere and It's not working.

Code:

```
dirname = File.dirname("C:/ProgramFiles/RubyLists")

require 'fileutils'

unless File.directory?(dirname)
  File.mkdir(dirname)
end  #This block will make the directory.

print("Mk. Worked.")
```

Error:

```
C:/Users/User/RubymineProjects/rubylists/main.rb:6:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `makedir' for File:Class (NoMethodError)
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

If you need anymore info let me know and I will provide it if I can. Thanks!

Comment: Include the code and error here in the post please..

Comment: I tried and it would mess up. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: The error message is mentioning a `makedir` method that is nowhere to be seen in the code you posted, can you please fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`FileUtils::mkdir`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-mkdir) exist, not `File::mkdir`.

Thus change `File.mkdir(dirname)` to `FileUtils.mkdir(dirname)`.

Write your code :-

```
dirname = "C:/ProgramFiles/RubyLists"

require 'fileutils'

unless Dir.exist?(dirname)
  FileUtils.mkdir(dirname)
end  #This block will make the directory.

print("Mk. Worked.")
```

Comment: That did it, except the folder isn't showing up in the Program Files.

Comment: Take a look at the [`Pathname`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html) class, it is a kind of façade to `File`, `FileUtils`, `Dir`, and more.

Comment: @Agoldfish That's cause your dirname is "ProgramFiles"

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using `FileUtils` you can use `mkdir`

```
FileUtils.mkdir("a/b/c")
```

though if any of the parent folders don't exist it would just crash. I typically use `mkdir_p` since it recursively  creates directories as needed (unless I want it to crash, for example if the folder names were wrong)

Answer (score 1):

```
# function for create folder
def createFolder(folderName)
@folderName=folderName
  if File.directory?(@folderName)
  return "The Folder "+@folderName+" already exist"
  else
  Dir.mkdir(@folderName,0700)
  return "Created"
  end
end
```

to call it just type

```
createFolder('folderName')
```

Comment: @Monk_Code It's weird and pretty ugly, but it does work.